# how i can add the plugin identity-vault?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic4, biometrics, npm-registry

I have a problem when i add identity-vault plugin by cordova :

codova plugin add  @ionic-enterprise/identity-vault

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/@ionic-enterprise%2fidentity-vault - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@ionic-enterprise/identity-vault@3.6.3' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'cs-demo-ac-iv-master'

Comment: Its a paid plugin, you need to have account for enterprise

Comment: i should pay to have account for entreprise?

Comment: Maybe you contact them here https://ionicframework.com/enterprise/contact

Comment: thank you @Mostafa